# How to change a variable value with onclick?

Tags: laravel

I have a variable in my view which I want it's value to change according to a button I press. I tried this but It doesn't work:

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="{{ $product1 = $p->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Pick</button>
```

This is inside a @foreach. Is there a way to have the $product1 variable change it's value with the button click? Preferably pure HTML or Laravel. If not, then how do I do it? Javascript?

Comment: `onclick` is a javascript event and it is executed on the client side, you cannot change the value of a variable that is processed on the server, that variable will not even be there, there is only its value

Comment: So there's really no way to do it then?

Comment: Nope, the variable will not be there when the page has already been served, but maybe it's value is and you can change the value. But I don't really know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily using a Vue component, create a button for picking the product like so:

```
<button v-bind:class="buttonColor" @click="pickProduct" v-text="buttonText"></button>
```

Then create your function to make an Ajax call to update that product and at the same time update your button based on the response.

```
    methods: {
    pickProduct() {
            axios.post('/product/' + this.productId)
                .then(response => {
                    this.status = response.data;
                    }
                })
    }
```

then just realtime update the button copy and maybe color for when a product is picked

```
computed: {
    buttonText() {
        return (this.status=='picked') ? 'Picked' : 'Pick Product';
    },
    buttonColor() {
        return (this.status=='picked') ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-secondary';
    }
}
```

If you are looking for an easy solution I would think something like this could work for you.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- in your foreach !-->
@foreach($data as $p)
<!-- data-target #openModal{{$p->id}} !-->
<a role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openModal{{$p->id}}" ></a>
<!-- id = #openModal{{$p->id}} !-->
<div class="modal fade" id="openModal{{$p->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- here your code, for example you can display the id or any data 
!-->
        <p>Your id: {{$p->id}}</p>
        <!-- <p>Your name: {{$p->name}}</p> !-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

You can do this with boostrap,I leave you an example.
This is only to show data, if you want to modify data you have to use js